# Как разделить список на группы по должностям?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть список:

```
['Захарычев', 'Junior-Разработчик', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**']
['test-case(spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**']
['test-case(lead-spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**']
['test-case(tail-spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**']
['Чукалов', 'инженер', '49999', '8(***)***-**-**']
['Безенков', 'инженер', '40000', '8(***)***-**-**']
['Королёв', 'web-программист', '30000', '8(***)***-__-__']
['ы', 'хирург', '220000', '8(***)***-__-__']
['ы', 'терапевт', '25000', '8(***)***-__-__']
['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__']
['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__']
['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__']
['ы', 'Senior-developer', '330000', '8(***)***-__-__']
['ы', 'Senior-developer', '345000', '8(***)***-__-__']
['ы', 'Middle-developer', '150000', '8(***)***-__-__']
```

Как правильней всего разделить список на списки с одинаковыми должностями?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

очень не однозначный вопрос. где гарантии, что список будет всегда именно таким? а если порядок аргументов поменяется? к тому же опечатка или же написание с заглавной буквы это уже по сути другая должность с `точки зрения программы`. я бы воспользовался словарем.

```py
dictionary = {}
for element in lst:
    position = element[1].lower()
    if position not in dictionary.keys():
        dictionary[position]= [element]
    else:
        dictionary[position].append(element)
```

это то, как можно гарантировать, что должности с одинаковым упорядоченным набором букв даже в разных регистрах попадут в одну категорию.

Comment: `position = element[1].lower();
    dictionary.setdefault(position, []).append(element)`

Comment: `if position not in dictionary.keys():` лучше заменить на `if dictionary.get(position)`. Усложняете поиск.

Comment: молодцы молодцы) я писал это лишь для понимания. мне не особо понравился вопрос, да и путей решения у него красивых нет.

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [['Захарычев', 'Junior-Разработчик', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**'],
['test-case(spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**'],
['test-case(lead-spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**'],
['test-case(tail-spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**'],
['Чукалов', 'инженер', '49999', '8(***)***-**-**'],
['Безенков', 'инженер', '40000', '8(***)***-**-**'],
['Королёв', 'web-программист', '30000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'хирург', '220000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'терапевт', '25000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'Senior-developer', '330000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'Senior-developer', '345000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'Middle-developer', '150000', '8(***)***-__-__']]

res = {}
for k, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[1]):
    res.setdefault(k, list(g))
```

res (вывод для красоты сделал с помощью pretty print):

```
{   'Junior-Разработчик': [   [   'Захарычев',
                                  'Junior-Разработчик',
                                  '50000',
                                  '8(916)523-**-**']],
    'Middle-developer': [   [   'ы',
                                'Middle-developer',
                                '150000',
                                '8(***)***-__-__']],
    'Senior-developer': [   [   'ы',
                                'Senior-developer',
                                '330000',
                                '8(***)***-__-__'],
                            [   'ы',
                                'Senior-developer',
                                '345000',
                                '8(***)***-__-__']],
    'test': [   ['test-case(spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**'],
                ['test-case(lead-spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**'],
                ['test-case(tail-spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**']],
    'web-программист': [   [   'Королёв',
                               'web-программист',
                               '30000',
                               '8(***)***-__-__']],
    'инженер': [   ['Чукалов', 'инженер', '49999', '8(***)***-**-**'],
                   ['Безенков', 'инженер', '40000', '8(***)***-**-**']],
    'терапевт': [['ы', 'терапевт', '25000', '8(***)***-__-__']],
    'уборщица': [   ['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
                    ['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
                    ['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__']],
    'хирург': [['ы', 'хирург', '220000', '8(***)***-__-__']]}
```

Еще есть вариант использовать pandas. В этом случае я выведу результат в виде словаря словарей, с которым, возможно, будет удобнее работать:

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.DataFrame(lst).groupby(1).agg(list).to_dict(orient="index")
```

res:

```
{   'Junior-Разработчик': {   0: ['Захарычев'],
                              2: ['50000'],
                              3: ['8(916)523-**-**']},
    'Middle-developer': {0: ['ы'], 2: ['150000'], 3: ['8(***)***-__-__']},
    'Senior-developer': {   0: ['ы', 'ы'],
                            2: ['330000', '345000'],
                            3: ['8(***)***-__-__', '8(***)***-__-__']},
    'test': {   0: [   'test-case(spaces)',
                       'test-case(lead-spaces)',
                       'test-case(tail-spaces)'],
                2: ['50000', '50000', '50000'],
                3: ['8(916)523-**-**', '8(916)523-**-**', '8(916)523-**-**']},
    'web-программист': {0: ['Королёв'], 2: ['30000'], 3: ['8(***)***-__-__']},
    'инженер': {   0: ['Чукалов', 'Безенков'],
                   2: ['49999', '40000'],
                   3: ['8(***)***-**-**', '8(***)***-**-**']},
    'терапевт': {0: ['ы'], 2: ['25000'], 3: ['8(***)***-__-__']},
    'уборщица': {   0: ['ы', 'ы', 'ы'],
                    2: ['15000', '15000', '15000'],
                    3: [   '8(***)***-__-__',
                           '8(***)***-__-__',
                           '8(***)***-__-__']},
    'хирург': {0: ['ы'], 2: ['220000'], 3: ['8(***)***-__-__']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

в принципе, тот же результат можно получить и без groupby:

```
lst = [['Захарычев', 'Junior-Разработчик', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**'],
['test-case(spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**'],
['test-case(lead-spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**'],
['test-case(tail-spaces)', 'test', '50000', '8(916)523-**-**'],
['Чукалов', 'инженер', '49999', '8(***)***-**-**'],
['Безенков', 'инженер', '40000', '8(***)***-**-**'],
['Королёв', 'web-программист', '30000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'хирург', '220000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'терапевт', '25000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'уборщица', '15000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'Senior-developer', '330000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'Senior-developer', '345000', '8(***)***-__-__'],
['ы', 'Middle-developer', '150000', '8(***)***-__-__']]

res = {}
for l in lst:
    res.setdefault(l[1], []).append(l)
```